# CI3/ Validation Rules to a Config File & Using a callback

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am unable to figure out where to place my callback when using validation rules to a config file in CI3.  Here is my form_validation.php:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 $config = array(
   'blog_post' => array(

      array(
        'field' => 'entry_name', 
        'label' => 'entry_name', 
        'rules' => 'min_length[8]|trim|required|max_length[255]'
        ),

      array(
        'field' => 'entry_body', 
        'label' => 'entry_body', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[12]|callback_html_length_without_html'
        ),
    ),
);

function html_length_without_html(){
   if (2 < 1)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('html_length_without_html', 'The field can not be the word');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

However, when I run the above, I get the following error:

```
 Unable to access an error message corresponding 
 to your field name entry_body.(html_length_without_html)
```

Where do I place the callback "html_length_without_html()"?

Comment: Maybe reading the user guide will shed some light on the answer. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Yes, have read that and obviously not getting it.

Comment: Well that function would go in the controller where you are performing the actual validation. The same controller where you are using the form validation config to configure the validation rules.

Comment: Also you would need to define a parameter in your callback to perform your check against. Just like in the documentation that you might need to glance over again :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I already have this in a method in a controller:   $this->form_validation->set_data($data); if ($this->form_validation->run('blog_post') != false) { // so I have to run another form valication locally to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [extend](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html?highlight=extending#extending-helpers) or create a method inside the controller. I do prefer to "extend" with a helper function. Assuming that you are using `$_POST`:

**application/helpers/form_validation_helper.php** or just extending with MY_form_helper.php:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!function_exists('html_length_without_html')) {

function html_length_without_html() {
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $entry_body = $ci->input->post('entry_body');
    /*Do some check here to define if is TRUE or FALSE*/
    if ($entry_body < 1) {
        $ci->form_validation->set_message('html_length_without_html', 'The field can not be the word');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

}
```

Nothing wrong with `$ci->form_validation->set_message('html_length_without_html', 'The field can not be the word');`, but if you're using the lang class, you should save the following line into `application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php` to get successfull callback response:

```
$lang['html_length_without_html'] = 'The field can not be the word';
```

Don't forget to load the helper before use it: `$this->load->helper('form_validation_helper');` or [autoload](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=loading#auto-loading-resources), instead.

Comment: Correction: It should be $this->load->helper('form_validation'); the _helper.php part is implied as it is a helper.

Comment: deleted this comment.

Comment: I am using POST, PUT (GET, DELETE).  Of course, POST and PUT are the culprits that would be affected.  This is through Phil Sturgeon's API server.

Comment: If you use `$this->load->helper('form_validation');`, @timbrownlaw, you're gonna get a error message. Pay attention to the name of the file **which is determined by the developer.**

Comment: @ShutUpMagda Actually the inclusion/exclusion of the _helper part of the helper file name in the helper loader doesn't make a jot of difference as both cases are acceptable.I actually tested it! You live and learn...

Comment: Don't matter, @timbrownlaw, because I decided to put the suffix, man, and the declaration should observe this. What's wrong with that?