# Codeigniter Form Validation Callback Issue

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have this code below. My problem is it only triggers the callback. The required and valid_email rules are not called. I'm expecting to execute the rules in order. But when I remove the callback it runs normal. TIA.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('search_word', 'Email address', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_has_valid_credentials');

$this->form_validation->set_message('has_valid_credentials', '{field} is not registered in the system.');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

    $this->load->view('login/reset');
    return;
    }
```

Comment: Did you define a function that named has_valid_credentials ?

Comment: Please, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40836772/6054930) ;)

Comment: @ErolKESKİN yes, i have function named has_valid_credentials. I tried with the prefix `callback_has_valid_credentials` and it searched thru the db. I also tried without the **callback_ prefix** and the required and valid_email are both working but the callback is not. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a function named `has_valid_credentials` defined.

```
public function has_valid_credentials($str) {
    /** Write validation code here **/
}
```

For your reference, check out the documentation.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Sorry. I did not include the has_valid_credentials function code but I have. I'm just pointing out the issue that whenever I include the callback, the two other rules are not triggered, only the callback.